# Recommendation for a web app to track Time, like a Time Clock at work?

Tags: webapp-rec

I'm an independent contractor, and work on many different jobs throughout a given day...

I'm trying to find a decent web-app based time clock so I can use my phone or the computer to access it.  It is important for me to easily dump this data out to another usable format (CSV / API / Reports / etc).

### Requested Features:

*Note: not all features are required, just some ideas of what will become my accepted answer*

- Clock In / Clock Out entries
- Manual entries (1 hour doing something where I wasn't at the computer)
- Job Tracking (which client am I working for, what task?)
- Reporting

  - I would love to see reports per day/week/client/etc.
  - Even a CSV export of data would be usable for me
- Assistance with Billing using paypal/or even printable invoices would be amazing.
- Ability to have multiple users on the same "time clock" account would be a bonus as well. (Imagine being the boss of 2 or 3 employees and needing to see their time clocks as well)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[Track My Hours](http://trackmyhours.com) - without a doubt has the exact feature set you are looking for:

1. Can track hours, with clock in/clock out functionality
2. Can do manual entries, also can specify that some employees can't do manual entries (important for us, because our min wage employees we don't want editing their hours)
3. Tracks unlimited number of Jobs and clients, or can be used for internal use only (In other words it works as a "time clock" for hourly employees, but also a task manager for consultants.
4. Very good reporting interface.
5. Tracks invoices, printable versions, and which ones were paid in simple and efficient manner.
6. Unlimited employees/consultants

Comment: Post Script - 30 Day Free Trial, $9/mo for everything unlimited. (No price scaling!)

Comment: best deal I've seen.

Comment: This looks pretty amazing, and challenges Al's assumption that a "single best answer" wouldn't be found.  I think that out of the 18 answers currently available this one easily rises to the top with my list of requirements.  Thanks a bunch!  It can even export to QuickBooks, which is grand!

Answer (score 3):

[Rescue Time](http://www.rescuetime.com) is another option, automatically tracks your time spent on each active window.

Comment: This looks very cool, however, it isn't a Web Application that I could also use from my phone.

Comment: Doesn't seem to really do everything he asks for. VD.

Comment: meh - i like trackmyhours.com better. Easier to use.

Comment: I really don't like web app which need addition OS's app to work with :)

Answer (score 1):

We use [TickSpot](http://tickspot.com/) for time tracking in our business, It fulfils the majority of your feature requests.

Comment: I have used Tick in the past. I liked it. Our company uses FogBugz so that's what I use for time tracking now (though I am not a huge fan of it's time tracking support).

Comment: looks too overdone

Comment: Tick is the best for tracking your time to hit your budget.

Answer (score 1):

How about Freckle? http://letsfreckle.com/

Comment: I love the design but it's not free :P

Answer (score 0):

Check out Kimai. It's the best I've encountered so far and it is open source and actually quite simple so if you have some programming knowledge you can even adapt it to your needs (I did it). 
http://www.kimai.org/en/

Answer (score 0):

Some Time trackers for consideration:

- [Klok](http://klok.mcgraphix.com/klok/index.htm) (Runs on Adobe AIR)
- [Manic Time](http://www.manictime.com/) (Windows)
- [Slim Timer](http://slimtimer.com/) (Web-based)

Answer (score 0):

Check NotePub.com, it does not have all the features you ask for, but it is very nice to use. Each note has a timer running since it was last modified.

Answer (score 0):

Billing application [Freshbooks](http://www.freshbooks.com/) has a widget that does most if not all of what you require. I'm very happy with this app.

Answer (score 0):

I've been using [Toggl](http://www.toggl.com) and I like it.  I don't think it hits all of those features, but does do some.

Answer (score 0):

A couple of very nice looking ones I've come across in the past. I've not used *any* of them, so YMMV

- http://www.subernova.com/ - this one is drop dead *gorgeous* :-)
- http://www.freshbooks.com/ - looks to be well loved and has lots of features

Answer (score 0):

[1daylater](http://1daylater.com/) - Most the features you requested.  Very clean very easy to use.  I've been using it for 6-8 months now.

I think the only feature it lacks is the boss view you requested.

Answer (score 0):

http://colorhat.com/

Is the best, without a fling.

Answer (score 0):

I liked [ClockingIt](http://clockingit.com) pretty much as long as I used it. It is free, you can host it yourself if you want:

- no restrictions or limits
- one-click time tracking
- clean and out of the way interface
- interactive gantt chart & scheduling
- flexible reporting
- multiple ways to communicate
- tracks and indexes all changes
- notifications via email, rss & ical
- ajax, comet & drag and drop
- translated to 14 languages

Comment: Open Source, MIT License, built on Rails... I like it!

Answer (score 0):

I use Paymo [time tracker](http://www.paymo.biz) , it pretty much has all the features you listed.

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend giving [timr.com](http://timr.com) a try! In addition to its web interface it also provides clients for iPhone, Android and BlackBerry devices.

Answer (score 0):

We use http://www.getharvest.com/ for time tracking. It has project budgets, different billing rates, alerts and stats about budgets, it can also do invoices.

Comment: If literally all you need is a time clock, don't use Harvest. But if you want something to track your time per project, integrate it with an hourly rate / billing / invoicing, Harvest is GREAT.

Answer (score 0):

+1 I was going to ask this same question!

I have used [intervals](http://www.myintervals.com/)- they have a free plan and their timer system is pretty nice.  You have to pay to get large scale features like invoicing and time tracking across multiple separate projects.

They also just launched a version of their site optimized for mobile browsers.  Haven't used it much though as I don't code on my mobile device (yet).

I am interested in alternatives though- mostly because Intervals feels a bit too heavyweight for my current level of contract activity.  If I had employees working under me it would be the perfect fit.

Answer (score 0):

I've used the online app [tiktrac](http://tiktrac.com/), which has most but not all of the features you're looking for (mobile access yes, invoicing no, ....). I like its simplicity and the timer feature.

Answer (score 0):

I believe that [mite](http://mite.yo.lk) has most of the features your requested. I recently came across a new app, that is not live yet called [clockmeister](http://www.clockmeister.com), which also has most features. Site looks promising.

> mite is a sleek online tool for collecting and analyzing labor. Designed in close collaboration with and for teams and freelancers: advertising agencies, architects, lawyers, designers, universities and so on.

---

> clockmeister is a web-based time tracking system with simple and intuitive time tracking. Precise calculations combined with flexible reporting. Try out the 30 Day free trial.

Answer (score 0):

[Hours Tracking](http://hourstracking.com) is another good option. It has all of the features you requested other than invoicing. Instead, you can create customizable reports that work with Quickbooks or another invoicing system. Pricing is $1 per user, per month after a free trial. As an administrator, you can add as many users as you want.

Comment: Please disclose your affiliation with the service you mentioned. Otherwise your answer will be considered spam and treated accordingly. Thanks!